# fresh install of windows 7 sp1, original dvd, hang on starting windows, before logo animation

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze, computer-building, fresh-install

new build;

```
asus z87-a
intel i5-4670K
intel ssd 180g 530
western digital black 2t
LG CH12NS3012X BD-ROM
msi geforce 760
antec high current gamer 750W
Kingston KHX1600C9D3B1K2/8GX 8GB Kit
Noctua NH-D14
```

I did update the bios and the intel ssd firmware

while trying to install from a `windows 7 home premium dvd(original) with sp1` i was getting stuck at starting windows, before the logo start.

i tried with a valid `windows 7 home premium DVD without sp1` and I was able to install, put driver in, do the whole windows update.

now from cold start, i'm randomly getting hang at the same place.

"Starting windows", before the logo start.

I have to press reset or do hard shutdown then i get the usual windows didn't start properly, repair or normal windows start.

repair does not work but allow me to start, same with normal windows start

once i was able to see what happen with `os boot information` from `msconfig`

it hang at loading `\windows\system32\config`
it never load a driver

the C: is the ssd so i did a chksdk on it no issue found, i also ran the basic test from the intel toolbox, no issue found

i wont have access to this computer for a few days and i did search online for solution so next time i will be sitting in front of that computer i will try:

```
uninstalling the intel RST (something tell me this is it)
remove battery, reset bios, etc
unplug the dvd and harddrive 
play with cable to make sure everything is fine
change the sata port of the ssd
check psu voltage in bios / monitoring application
```

should i do anything else?

Comment: The \windows\system32\config folder is where the registry lives.

Comment: make a LiveCD/LiveDVD from linux.  OpenSuSe, redhat, or whatever.  Do they boot correctly?  Could be memory timings does your memory match what the BIOS says? CAS,RAS,CL, and etc

Comment: Check to see which mode the SATA controller was in during install, should be AHCI. Try changing mem speed to 1300 and underclock CPU to see if it is not in the storage system. Triple check all the power cables. Do a thermal stress test in Windows to check if cooling system is functioning.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.

You could try to solve it by changing the boot mode in your BIOS from UEFI to CMS, and then reinstalling Windows 7.